# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un setTimeout() más preciso?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Trabajo con **NodeJS**, y hace un momento, me he dado cuenta de un serio problema con los `timers`, no son 100% fiables

https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args
[image: https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args]

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  const filename = `${channel.tracker}-${channel.id}-${channel.trackertimer}.txt`;
  const userfriendly = `${msg.author.username}-#${client.channels.get(channel.id).name}.txt`;
  fs.access(filename, fs.constants.R_OK | fs.constants.W_OK, (err) => {
    if (err) return;
    msg.author.sendFile(filename, userfriendly, `The time ended! There's your file for ${channel}.`)
      .then(() => {
        channel.tracking = false;
        channel.tracker = null;
        channel.trackertimer = null;
        fs.unlink(filename, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
      });
  });
}, 900000);
```

Pero claro, como ya mencioné, no es del todo preciso, debería mandar el mensaje tras `900000`ms (15 minutos), pero a veces lo hace en 5 minutos.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el siguiente código envíe el mensaje con un error menor de 10 segundos? He intentado usar un `while` pero no logré hacer que recorriera el `setTimeout` (de otra manera estaría recorriendo el loop cada ms).

Adicionalmente, éste es el objeto `channel`:

```
TextChannel {
  type: 'text',
  id: '256955088612884481',
  name: 'bot-test',
  position: 19,
  permissionOverwrites: [Object],
  topic: null,
  lastMessageID: '274834083845242881',
  guild: [Object],
  messages: [Object],
  _typing: [Object],
  lastMessage: [Object],
  tracking: true,
  tracker: '242043489611808769',
  trackertimer: 1485595942570
}
```

Comment: Podrías usar el paquete [`clocktick`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clocktick), es bastante acertado.

Comment: Aunque la idea es hacerlo sin usar librerías externas... ¿sabes cómo funciona `clocktick`?

Comment: Está bien que quieras hacerlo por tí mismo, pero también trata de no reinventar la rueda. Si quieres saber cómo funciona, mira el código fuente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo que la mejor opción sería jugar con las fechas:

```
function timer() {
  //Ponlo en segundos y luego en la función ya lo comparas en milisegundos
  var countDownTime = 15;
  //La fecha inicial
  var date = new Date();
  date = date.getTime();
  var check = setInterval(function() {
    //La fecha actual
    var nowDate = new Date();
    nowDate = nowDate.getTime();
    //Calculas la diferencia            
    var difference = nowDate - date;
    //Lo comparas
    if (difference >= countDownTime * 1000) {
      //Enviar el mensaje o hacer lo que quieras
      alert(difference);
      //Limpias el intervalo
      clearInterval(check);
    }
  }, true);
}
```

Comment: El `setInterval` está recorriendo el código cada 1ms (`true` == `1`), los argumentos de `setInterval` en **NodeJS** es `setInterval(callback, delay[, ...args])`

Comment: Lo que he hecho ha sido un ejemplo sencillo con JS para que se vea más o menos una manera de hacerlo preciso, y por 1 ms no creo que importe mucho (en este caso).

Comment: Solucionado [aquí](http://pastebin.com/60pTq8cN), ha mandado el mensaje con mucha precisión y no ha sido "code blocking", aunque haré más pruebas.

Answer (score 0):

La documentación se refiere a la falta de garantía con que ejecutará en el siguiente loop disponible del gestor de eventos después de transcurrido el tiempo solicitado, no antes.

Me parece que tu caso es que estás llamando dos o más veces el mismo timeout y se van solapando las ejecuciones.

Todas las librerías o soluciones que encuentres para gestionar tiempos funcionarán a partir de timeout o interval, por lo que en cualquier caso, la precisión será la misma.

Comment: Hombre, pues claro, es una aplicación dirigida para +1000 usuarios en más de 10 servidores, en ningún momento puedo darles a los administradores de alguno de los servidores, una herramienta imprecisa.